# How/why does this "divisible by 17" gimmick work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Take any 16 digit number, where the first group of 4 digits is repeated 3 more times, e.g.
1,234,123,412,341,234 is such a number.  Such a number is always divisible by 17.  It even works when starting with zero:  0432043204320432  !  I did not expect that!

How is it that this is true?  I've got as far as noting that such a number, if the digits are i,j,k and l, is composed of:

i,jkl,000,000,000,000 + ijk,l00,000,000 + ij,kl0,000 + i,jkl

So, what is special about adding up these terms:
i,jkl +  (i,jkl * 10,000) + (i,jkl * 100,000,000) + (i,jkl * 1,000,000,000,000) ?

Can someone with more math skills explain (slowly) why this works?  Thank you!

Comment: Any such number is also divisible by $73,173$ and $5882353.$

Comment: This is an example of how if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ then $a\mid c$.  Here, $17\mid 1000100010001$ and $1000100010001\mid 1000100010001\cdot \overline{ijkl}$ so...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use relevant tags. This has nothing to do with linear algebra.

Comment: When I was a kid, I enjoyed the following little calculator trick: 1. Pick a 3 digit number of your choice, 2. Multiply it by 7, 3 Multiply it by 11, then 4. Multiply it by 13. What do you get? You get your 3 digit number repeated twice, e.g. if you start with $456$, you get $456456$. It's the same idea: $7 \times 11 \times 13 = 1001$.

Comment: You came so close! You just needed to use the distributive property of multiplication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $x$ is the four-digit number, then $x + x \cdot 10000 + x \cdot 100000000 + x \cdot 1000000000000$ factors as $x \cdot (1 + 10000 + 100000000 + 1000000000000)$ or $x \cdot 1000100010001$, and $1000100010001$ is divisible by $17$.

Comment: Specifically, 1000100010001 = 17 * 58829412353 = 17 * 37 * 137 * 5882353.

Comment: $1000100010001=$ $1+10^4+10^8+10^{12}=$ $(1+10^4)+10^8(1+10^4)=$ $(1+10^8)(1+10^4)$ and  $17|(1+10^8).$

Answer (score 4):

No gimmicks

$$10^2\equiv-2\pmod{17}$$

$$\implies10^4\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4$$

$$10^8\equiv\cdots\equiv-1$$

$$1+10^4+10^8+10^{12}\equiv1+4+(-1)+(-4)\equiv0\pmod{17}$$

More generally for $a^4\ne1,$

$$1+a^4+a^8+a^{12}=\dfrac{a^{16}-1}{a^4-1}$$

Now for $a^4\not\equiv1\pmod{17},$ use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html

Comment: @BrianMoehring, Thanks for your observation

Comment: Don't know why is this downvoted.